How to simulate webhook with payload from GitHub to my Probot app using Postman?
I need to write a Probot App for GitHub that will respond when issue is opened.
To trigger my App that installed on one of the repos I need to create an issue on GitHub manually.
I run my app locally and every time I create issue on GitHub my app responds correctly.
However, I would like to simulate this request in Postman to make it easier.
I am trying this out with basic app:
/**
 * This is the main entrypoint to your Probot app
 * @param {import('probot').Probot} app
 */
export default (app) => {
  // Your code here
  app.log.info("Yay, the app was loaded!");

  app.on("issues.opened", async (context) => {
    const issueComment = context.issue({
      body: "Thanks for opening this issue!",
    });

    return context.octokit.issues.createComment(issueComment);
  });
};

This is console when my app is running locally:
INFO (probot): Yay, the app was loaded!
INFO (server): Running Probot v13.3.0 (Node.js: v20.14.0)
INFO (server): Forwarding https://smee.io/AAAAAAAAAAAA to http://localhost:3000/api/github/webhooks
INFO (server): Listening on http://localhost:3000

My app uses .env file that holds:
APP_ID, PRIVATE_KEY, WEBHOOK_PROXY_URL, WEBHOOK_SECRET, GITHUB_CLIENT_ID, GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET
In the settings of the app on GitHub one can see recent deliveries:
pic showing recent deliveries from github
There you can press also to redeliver.
AS can be seen on the picture there is content of header and payload.
In Postman on my local machine I am making POST http://localhost:3000/api/github/webhooks with exactly the same header and payload. However this is the response:
{"error":"Error: [@octokit/webhooks] signature does not match event payload and secret"}
What am I missing? Some authorization set besides headers and body in Postman?
